# How can I find a number of True statements in an Array of Bools in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, boolean

I am a new developer and cannot seem to figure out how to find the number of True statements in an Array of Booleans. I know how to find by index but not by value. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
let arrayElement = [Bool](repeating: false, count: 10)
var before: [[Bool]] = [[Bool]](repeating: arrayElement, count:10)
for i in 0 ..< 10 {
    for j in 0 ..< 10 {
        if arc4random_uniform(3) == 1 {
            before[i][j] = true  
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

#### Methods for counting number of `true` entries in a 1D array

One method would be to filter your array of `Bool` elements (for `true`) and simply count the number of remaining elements in the filtered array

```
let arr = [false, true, true, false, true]
let numberOfTrue = arr.filter{$0}.count
print(numberOfTrue) // 3
```

Another approach is to `reduce` (unfold) the array and increment a counter for each element that equals `true`

```
let arr = [false, true, true, false, true]
let numberOfTrue = arr.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 1 : 0) }
print(numberOfTrue) // 3
```

Or, a traditional `for` loop (with conditional in loop signature) approach, comparable top the `reduce` method:

```
let arr = [false, true, true, false, true]
var trueCounter = 0
for bElem in arr where bElem { trueCounter += 1 }
print(trueCounter) // 3
```

#### Applied to your example: use `joined()` to achieve a 1D array

The methods above can easily be applied to an array of arrays (of `Bool` elements: type `[[Bool]]`) by simply applying `.joined()` on the `[[Bool]]` array to sequentially construct a `[Bool]` array.

```
/* 'before' is of type [[Bool]], constructed as described
   in the question */
let numberOfTrueAlt1 = before.joined().filter{$0}.count

let numberOfTrueAlt2 = before.joined().reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 1 : 0) }

var numberOfTrueAlt3 = 0
for bElem in before.joined() where bElem { numberOfTrueAlt3 += 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with an array of arrays, the computation will have two steps as well. First, use `map` to convert each inner array to its truth count, and then aggregate with `reduce` to obtain the final result:

```
let countTrue = before.map {$0.filter{$0}.count}.reduce(0, +)
```