# Is there a way to retrieve directly the value returned from a closure in Swift, with type the return type of the closure and not: () -> Type

Tags: swift, closures

This is a question that aims merely at elegance, but is there a way to make something to the following code work in Swift? I know the code does not work, what I want is that the result of the code within the closure is stored in a constant. And the underlying theoretical issue is whether or not it is possible to retrieve the returned value from the closure with type Int and not with type () -> Int.
Thanks a lot for any help or comment!

```
let tableWithBooleans: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: 10)

tableWithBooleans[0] = true

tableWithBooleans[5] = true

let numberOfTrue: Int = {
            
    var result: Int = 0
            
    for i in 0...9 {
                
        if tableWithBooleans[i] {
                        
            result += 1
                        
        }
                                
    }

    return result

}

// I want the code to compile and numberOfTrue to be a constant equal to 2
```

Comment: That code cannot crash because it does not even compile.

Comment: You're right :) I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a high-order function instead

```
let numberOfTrue = tableWithBooleans.reduce(0) { $1 ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
```

Now if you still want to use your closure code then you should add a () after the closing } since you are calling the code inside {} as a function

```
let numberOfTrue: Int = {
    var result: Int = 0

    for i in 0...9 {
        if tableWithBooleans[i] {
            result += 1
        }
    }
    return result
}()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second solution was exactly what I was looking for (for use with more complex code) and the first solution is also a very useful thing to keep in mind.

Comment: More efficient (no intermediate array) would be `tableWithBooleans.reduce(0) { $1 ? $0 + 1 : $0 }` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985033/1187415).

Comment: or more readible, imo: `tableWithBooleans.lazy.map { $0 ? 1 : 0 }.reduce(0, +)`